# win32api.SendMessage not working when trying to release a button

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

i am trying to send some virtual keycodes to an application while it is out of focus. I get it to work without a problem except for releasing normal keys.

I have tried:

`win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, VK_CODE["a"])`

`win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, VK_CODE["a"])`

releasing a key works perfectly with the left mouse button:

`win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, 0)`

and using keydb_event:

`win32api.keybd_event(VK_CODE[i],0 ,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP ,0)`

But for some reason when trying to release a key using SendMessage it pressed down the button instead.

Comment: win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, VK_CODE["a"] )<- You missed the closing bracket. Is this a copy&paste error?

Comment: yes, its a copy&paste error, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

SendMessage lParam(0)
[image]

PostMessage lParam(0)
[image]

Keystroke Messages
[image]

```
INPUT inputs{};
inputs.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
inputs.ki.wVk = 0x41;
inputs.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
UINT uSent = SendInput(1, &inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
```

[image]

[Dead-Character Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#dead-character-messages)(such as The circumflex key on a German keyboard)

1. WM_KEYDOWN
2. WM_DEADCHAR
3. WM_KEYUP
4. WM_KEYDOWN
5. WM_CHAR
6. WM_KEYUP

It depends on how the application implements WM_KEYUP and then simulation is not reliable.
Attached a classic article [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: any way to record/test how the application implements keypresses?

Comment: Please consult the application author.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone reading this later on the problem was i wasn't specifying the Lparam in the function. this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54638862/20571682) explains it very well.

should also mention [SPY++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2022) which made understanding how keypresses in windows work a lot easier.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).